# Toggle that reveal text one at a time by click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, toggle, show-hide

I have a problem with my code. The goal is to have a text that appear when a user click on the link. But I want also that when he clicks on the link the only text that show is the text underneath and not in all the cells. Can someone has a clue on what I did wrong? I will probable add other links (more than 2) and I want to be sure that it will work every time.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".toggler").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.cat' + $(this).attr('data-prod-cat')).toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
a {
  color: #002642;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}

.toggler,
.cat1 {
  font-family: 'Varela Round';
  color: white;
}

td {
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  border: 1px dotted #c4a77d;
  background-color: #c4a77d;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 70em) {
  td {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px dotted #c4a77d;
    background-color: #c4a77d;
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
  }
}

p {
  font-family: 'Varela Round';
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5" style="table-layout: fixed; width:100%" width="100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table style="width: 100%;text-align:center;">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <p>SOCIÉTÉS: 230</p>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><a class="toggler" data-prod-cat="1" href="#">+ En savoir plus</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="cat1" style="display:none">
              <td>Part CAC 40 : 40</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="cat1" style="display:none">
              <td>Part Filiales +100MK€: 190</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td>
        <table style="width: 100%;text-align:center;">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <p>CONTACTS: 16 700</p>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><a class="toggler" data-prod-cat="1" href="#">+ En savoir plus</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="cat1" style="display:none">
              <td>Part CAC 40 : 10 000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="cat1" style="display:none">
              <td>Part Filiales +100MK€: 6 700</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>EMAIL NOMINATIF</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>OPT OUT</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>LIGNES DIRECTES/MOBILES</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have just to go up to the parent `table` using `closest('table')` function and then select all the text's related to the current clicked `.toggler` using `.find('[class^="cat"]')` like :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".toggler").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).closest('table').find('[class^="cat"]').toggle();
  });
});
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".toggler").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    $(this).closest('table').find('[class^="cat"]').toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
a {
  color: #002642;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}

.toggler,
.cat1 {
  font-family: 'Varela Round';
  color: white;
}

td {
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  border: 1px dotted #c4a77d;
  background-color: #c4a77d;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 70em) {
  td {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px dotted #c4a77d;
    background-color: #c4a77d;
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
  }
}

p {
  font-family: 'Varela Round';
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5" style="table-layout: fixed; width:100%" width="100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table style="width: 100%;text-align:center;">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <p>SOCIÉTÉS: 230</p>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><a class="toggler" data-prod-cat="1" href="#">+ En savoir plus</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="cat1" style="display:none">
              <td>Part CAC 40 : 40</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="cat1" style="display:none">
              <td>Part Filiales +100MK€: 190</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td>
        <table style="width: 100%;text-align:center;">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <p>CONTACTS: 16 700</p>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <a class="toggler" data-prod-cat="1" href="#">+ En savoir plus</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="cat1" style="display:none">
              <td>Part CAC 40 : 10 000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="cat1" style="display:none">
              <td>Part Filiales +100MK€: 6 700</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>EMAIL NOMINATIF</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>OPT OUT</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>LIGNES DIRECTES/MOBILES</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you know if it is possible with my code to align vertically my text. I'm trying to put tthem in the same line for a more harmonious aspect

Comment: Not sure what you mean by _align vertically my text_, give me an example please.

Comment: I want the ttitles in each cell to be at the same level because right now the texts that are not hidden don't appear "on the same line"; some are more up/down that the others

Comment: You mean for example : "SOCIÉTÉS: 230" & "+ En savoir plus" to be at the same line ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the **parent** of `<a>` first then get that **parent** which is `<tr>`. Finally **filter** on `cat1` class to toggle all siblings containing the `cat1` class.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".toggler").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().parent().siblings().filter(".cat1").toggle();
  });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".toggler").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().parent().siblings().filter(".cat1").toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
a {
  color: #002642;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}

.toggler,
.cat1 {
  font-family: 'Varela Round';
  color: white;
}

td {
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  border: 1px dotted #c4a77d;
  background-color: #c4a77d;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 70em) {
  td {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px dotted #c4a77d;
    background-color: #c4a77d;
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
  }
}

p {
  font-family: 'Varela Round';
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5" style="table-layout: fixed; width:100%" width="100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table style="width: 100%;text-align:center;">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <p>SOCIÉTÉS: 230</p>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><a class="toggler" data-prod-cat="1" href="#">+ En savoir plus</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="cat1" style="display:none">
              <td>Part CAC 40 : 40</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="cat1" style="display:none">
              <td>Part Filiales +100MK€: 190</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td>
        <table style="width: 100%;text-align:center;">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <p>CONTACTS: 16 700</p>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><a class="toggler" data-prod-cat="1" href="#">+ En savoir plus</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="cat1" style="display:none">
              <td>Part CAC 40 : 10 000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="cat1" style="display:none">
              <td>Part Filiales +100MK€: 6 700</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>EMAIL NOMINATIF</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>OPT OUT</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>LIGNES DIRECTES/MOBILES</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, I guess you are trying to use `data-prod-cat` attribute to know which block needs to appear.

But in both of your block you have `data-prod-cat="1"` which means that you will activate both blocks on every action.

Try changing the 2nd block attribute to :

```
data-prod-cat="2"
```

You'll also need to update the css class in your other `<tr>`